# Is MySQL internal encryption function enough for making system secure?

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

I'm working for start up company, using MySQL for Health care service.

Since my company provides health care service, there are lots of important data such as patient information.

We need to, and want to meet some compliance related to health information privacy, especially HIPAA&HITECH.

We have searched for several ways to protect our database.

As a result, we decided to encrypt our database.

And there were two general way to encrypt MySQL database, using MySQL internal encryption function and deploy some encryption solution.

However, we couldn't determine what to select.

Is MySQL internal encryption function enough for making system secure?
If not, what's the best?

Comment: Off topic. Try dba.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There is a freeware for encrypting MySQL databases . Check this website: [mydiamo](http://mydiamo.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying database encryption by internal encryption package provided by DBMS, it could be convenient for the user to apply. But not only convenience but also actual protection of the personal information is important when considering database encryption. It is common opinion of security professionals that encryption functions provided only by the DBMS is insufficient for safe protection of personal information. This is no exception for MySQL internal encryption functions.

First, MySQL internal encryption functions does not provide *key management.
When encrypting data, not only encryption itself but also managing key is important. The importance of the key cannot be stressed strongly enough when encryption matters. But most of encryption solutions does not pay much attention to the key. When using MySQL internal encryption functions, the key is exposed to the source, so there could be no proper key management.

Here is an example of a source code.

**INSERT into** userc (name, town) VALUES ('john',AES_ENCRYPT('nebraska', 'usa2010'));

**SELECT** CAST(AES_DECRYPT(town, 'usa2010') AS CHAR(50)) town_decrypt from userc;

You can see that the key ‘usa2010’ is exposed in the command.

Second, **data access control of users is difficult.
For proper access control for personal information, IP address, MAC address and access time should be controlled. By applying MySQL internal encryption function only, it is hard to provide proper access control.

Third, by applying MySQL internal encryption functions, query modification is needed.
You might think that it is easy to apply encryption by MySQL internal encryption functions. But in practice, you must modify application excessively to implement encryption by this method. This is because query modification is needed in MySQL internal encryption functions. In other words, the encryption function must be inserted into the query so that the data could be encrypted when it goes into the storage engine. Applying query modification can be a great burden to the implementers of DB encryption system.

Resultingly, I think deploying some encryption solution would be more secure for your data.

I can't confirm what is the best solution for you, since it depends on your circumstances. But I could provide you some examples.

If you want to encrypt almost every databases or columns, there are no difference between file-level encryption and another type encryption tools. In that case, you can find many file-level encryption tools like Gazzang's nZcrypt. http://www.gazzang.com/products/zncrypt

However, if you want to encrypt only few columns, I would like you to find Cell-level encryption or Column-level encryption tools. As I know in SQL Server, its' own encryption function supports Cell-level encryption, but I am not sure whether Cell-level encryption tools exists in MySQL. I have found Column-Level encryption software, MyDiamo. http://www.mydiamo.com

I hope this answer helps you a little.

Thank you.

---

*Key Management:
When converting data (plaintext) into cryptograph (ciphertext), ‘key’ is used. Similarly, the same key could be used in decryption. For secure encryption, encryption function is important, but management of the key is more important. Key management means more than preservation of key. It means applying encryption at some tier, and control decryption in particular tier after going through legitimate process and user authentication. That is, secure key management includes control of decryption authority.

**Data Access Control:
 If external people can access to one’s critical data easily, this can create great havoc. When generating, refining or saving data, we should consider security of data. With the key management, data access control, defining or restricting right to access data, need to be performed for secure encryption.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's internal encryption requires key management. Your patient info will be as vulnerable as your keys, and there's nothing in MySQL that helps make the keys secure. That will be a function of your application software. You'll have to write code to fetch and use the keys on every access. A cracker will be able to do what you do.

Plus, such things as patient medical record numbers themselves, in isolation, are protected health information. If you encrypt them, your users will have a difficult time finding their patients in your system.

Conclusion: encrypting your DBMS is both unnecessary and insufficient to protect patient data. It is a bad idea. You will, like every other US healthcare IT company, need to build a solid firewall between your internal network and the public network. You'll need to use TLS to conceal your patient data on the public network, and a solid authentication scheme to be sure your users are who they claim to be.  You'll need to hire an ISO29001 audit consultant to guide you in certifying your systems to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into TDE used in MS SQLServer enterprise edition 2012.  Oracle has a similar solution.  Most of the top EHR applications use these.  Also you look into WorldVista which is a tree database developed for the VA hospitals.  The server